# C# dataGridView update changes to database with thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I want to update changes from dataGridView to database with thread.

Here is the code:

```
    public void Updatewiththread()
    {
            DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

            if (changes != null)
            {

                MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter1);
                ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
                mySqlDataAdapter1.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
                mySqlDataAdapter1.Update(changes);
            }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

            if (changes != null)
            {
                UpdateThread = new Thread(Updatewiththread);
                UpdateThread.Start();
            }
    }
```

The problem is, when i change 1 value its working, but when i change another its not. When i sort random column its working again. In multiple changes sometime works sometime leave 1 cell's changes.

Comment: Interacting with UI components (dataGridView1) from a non-UI thread is never a good idea.

Comment: Why do you think you need a thread? Updates are usually pretty quick. `AcceptChanges` doesnt do what you think it does - it resets the RowState effectively throwing away any pending changes

Comment: @Plutonix If i change more than 100 value the form is freeze for a while.